# How to load manually data in kendo ui grid

Tags: c#, grid, kendo-ui

I have a kendo ui grid.
I want to load my grid manually. For example when my page loaded, the grid not loading, but when I click a button, data load in grid.
How to I can do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disable auto-loading from the grid's data source by setting the grid's [`autoBind`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-autoBind) property to `false` and then call [`read()`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods-read) on the data source when the button is clicked.